# How to receive Message from topic with Partition Enabled

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I have enabled partition for the topic and while sending message I have added the PartitionKey information too.

But when I try to receive message from that topic I am unable filter the message Which belongs only to the particular PartitionKey.

I have tried by using the below code. Its simply returning all messages without any filtering.

```
IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage> messages = mr.PeekBatch(100);
```

I'd be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

To send and receive messages into particular partition, you should use Sessions in Service Bus.

Enable `RequiresSession` property for the Topic and send the messages with `PartitionKey` or `SessionId`, so that you can receive messages from a particular Partition or Session by adding `AcceptMessageSession([PartitionKey])` before peeking the messages.

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-partitioning) for more details.

Comment: can you please suggest me how to add "RequiresSession" Property to a Topic, since i don't see anything like "RequiresSession" property while creating topic. @Arunprabhu

Comment: You cannot set RequiresSession property in Azure Portal. Try to use external tools like Service Bus Explorer or Serverless360 to set extended properties at the time of Topic creation.